# Most efficient way to get records from a table for which a record exists in another table for each month

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have two tables as below:

```
User: User_ID, User_name and some other columns (has approx 1000 rows)
Fee: Created_By_User_ID, Created_Date and many other columns (has 17 million records)
```

Fee table does not have any index (and I can't create one).

I need a list of users for each month of a year (say 2016) who have created at least one fee record.

I do have a working query below which is taking long time to execute. Can someone help me with a better query? May be using `EXIST` clause (I tried one but still takes time as it scans `Fee` table)

```
SELECT MONTH(f.Created_Date), f.Created_By_User_ID
FROM Fees f 
JOIN [User] u ON f.Created_By_User_ID= u.User_ID
WHERE f.Created_Date BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-12-31'
```

Comment: add `select DISTINCT`. If you need a list of users there is no need to select the whole lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will require a full scan of the fee table once in the original query you are using. If you use just the join directly, as you have in the original query, you will require multiple scans of the fee table, many of which will go through redundant rows while the join occurs. Same scenario will occur when you use an inner query as suggested by Mansoor.

An optimization could be to decrease the number of rows on which the joins are happening. 
Assuming that the user table contains only one record per user and the Fee table has multiple records per person, we can attempt to find distinct months users made a purchase for by using a CTE.
Then we can make a join on top of this CTE, this will reduce the computation performed by the join and should give a slightly better output time when performing over a large data set.

Try this:

```
WITH CTE_UserMonthwiseFeeRecords AS 
(
SELECT DISTINCT Created_By_User_ID, MONTH(Created_Date) AS FeeMonth
FROM Fee
WHERE Created_Date BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-12-31'
)
SELECT User_name, FeeMonth
FROM CTE_UserMonthwiseFeeRecords f 
INNER JOIN [User] u ON f.Created_By_User_ID= u.User_ID
```

Also, you have not mentioned that you require the user names and all, if only id is required for the purpose of finding distinct users making purchases per month, then you can just use the query within the CTE and not even require the `JOIN` as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Created_By_User_ID, MONTH(Created_Date) AS FeeMonth
FROM Fee
WHERE Created_Date BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-12-31'
```

Comment: Thanks @DK5. This query executed relatively quicker.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try below query :

SELECT MONTH(f.Created_Date), f.Created_By_User_ID
FROM Fees f 
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM [User] u WHERE f.Created_By_User_ID= u.User_ID 
AND DATEDIFF(DAY,f.Created_Date,'2016-01-01') <= 0 AND
    DATEDIFF(DAY,f.Created_Date,'2016-12-31') >= 0
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick response. But this query also takes time. Execution plan does show that this is little less expensive query.

Comment: This query actually takes more time because of the inner query using a variable from the outer query. This is not recommended and should slow down the performance further more than the original query.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this approach to reduce the query run time. however, It does duplicate the huge data and store a instance of table (Temp_Fees), On every DML performed on table Fees/User require truncate and fresh load of table  Temp_Fees.

```
Select * into Temp_Fees  from  (SELECT MONTH(f.Created_Date) as Created_MONTH, f.Created_By_User_ID
FROM Fees f 
WHERE f.Created_Date BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-12-31' )


SELECT f.Created_MONTH, f.Created_By_User_ID
FROM Temp_Fees  f 
JOIN [User] u ON f.Created_By_User_ID= u.User_ID
```